# request handlers using webapp2 tuple(regex, handler)

Tags: regex, python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

Edited my question because it wasn't very clear before.

**Code 1 working**

```
class AtSeaHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id=None):
        boat = ndb.Key(urlsafe=id).get()
        boat_dict = boat.to_dict()
        boat_dict['self'] = "/boats/" + id
        self.response.write(json.dumps(boat_dict)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
         ('/boats/([\w-]+)', AtSeaHandler)
      ], debug=True)
```

**Code 2 (not working)**

```
class AtSeaHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id=None):
        boat = ndb.Key(urlsafe=id).get()
        boat_dict = boat.to_dict()
        boat_dict['self'] = "/boats/" + id
        self.response.write(json.dumps(boat_dict)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
         ('/boats/([\w-]+)/at_sea', AtSeaHandler)
      ], debug=True)
```

Code 2 is a copy of code 1. Only difference between code 1 and code 2 is code 1 is ('/boats/([\w-]+)', AtSeaHandler) vs code 2 is ('/boats/([\w-]+)/at_sea', AtSeaHandler). Then I comment out code 1.

code 1 works. code 2 doesn't work with the /at_sea added. I entered http://localhost:8080/boats/aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIRCxIEQm9hdBiAgICAgPCLCww in postman and verifies code 1 works. Also tested code 2 and verifies it doesn't work.

What do I need to do to get this to work?  When I passed a `boat` entity key to ([\w-]+) and I `def get(self, id=None):` `id` is given the boat entity key.  Does at_sea need an argument in get()? Do i need to change the get() from get(self, id=none) to get(self, id=none, **argument3=none**)? Coming from C++, I keep thinking that it is like a function call with 3 arguments needs a function header with 3 parameters to hold those arguments. Am I totally misunderstanding things?

The [documentation](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#guide-routing) isn't helping me understand how to answer my question...

Comment: yup, my 1st suspicion is true: try http://localhost:8080/boats/aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIRCxIEQm9hdBiAgICAgPCLCww/at_sea to match the new pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do a tryout using a generic approach in the handler's `get()` code (whcih you can easily check with your browser), in the sense that it should work regardless of the regex pattern you have in the `app`'s router:

```
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.response.write('args: %s<br>kwargs: %s' % (args, kwargs))
```

The router works the same way for the `put()`, so you could apply a similar method, only it's a bit more difficult to see the results immediately - you'd have to use logging and check the app's logs.

With this you see exactly what args you get and how/where, so you can adapt your handler code as needed. You may need to repeat if you change the regex pattern.

With the code you posted (i.e. `def put():`) it shouldn't have worked at all as `id` is uninitialized. Which means you probably lost track of your changes.

To me `put(self, id=None):` is correct and should work for any pattern with **a single** `()` group in it.

You didn't exactly explain what do you mean by `stopped working` :) I have 2 suspicions:

- you didn't change the actual request to match the pattern. I mean a `boats/<some_safe_url>` request would match the `'/boats/([\w-]+)'` pattern, but will fail the `'/boats/([\w-]+)/at_sea'` pattern. You'd see a 404 error.
- you expected the request on `AtSeaHandler`, but you actually got it on `BoatHandler` (and maybe you didn't notice that). This happens because a `boats/<some_safe_url>/at_sea` pattern also matches the `'/boats/(.*)'` pattern and the router selects the first match. This unexpected match also produces an invalid `id`: `<some_safe_url>/at_sea` which will fail to get you a key and thus a boat - again a 404 error, or plain crash - a 500 error. You need to swap the order of the route definitions in the router, with the most specific pattern first.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the routing order and the (.*) was causing me the problem. Now it works! All the things I came across online didn't emphasize in order of route definitions and I didn't realize how (.*) gobbled up what comes after.  

The following order actually worked when i replaced (.*) with ([/w-]+)

('/boats/([\w-]+)/at_sea', AtSeaHandler), 
('/boats/([\w-]+)', BoatHandler)